# socket.io "connection" event isn't being called

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sockets, socket.io

I am trying to create a very simple server with express and socket.io. When I open the webpage (at `localhost:2000`), I can see the HTML file, but the `io.sockets.on("connection")` event is not called and I don't see `"socket connection"` in the console.

`app.js`:

```js
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var serv = require("http").Server(app);

app.get("/",function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/client/index.html");
});
app.use("/client", express.static(__dirname + "/client"));

serv.listen(2000)

var io = require("socket.io")(serv,{});
io.sockets.on("connection", function(socket) {
  console.log("socket connection")
});
```

`index.html`:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
<script>
var socket = io();
</script>
```

I previously installed `express` and `socket.io` through npm.

How can I fix this? I'm running `node.js v12.13.1`, `express 6.12.1`, and `socket.io 6.12.1` on macOS 11.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured this out. The CDN I had used was outdated.

In `index.html`, I replaced

```html
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
```

with

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/3.1.0/socket.io.js"></script>
```